# Angular not sending header on every request

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular 1.6.4. I'm trying to send an Auth header on every request, but the client doesn't seem to be sending the header in the request. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

This is my app.js

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'toolbar', 'authService'])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
    });
```

and my AuthInterceptor

```
angular.module('authService', [])
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function() {
    return function(config) {
        request: {
            config.headers.Authentication = 'thisIsATestToken';
            return config;
        }
    };
});
```

However, on the service side I never get the 'Authentication' header.

I've looked at my examples, and this is exactly how all of them do it. I'm just running the app locally on localhost.

Comment: Are you sure about sending the `Authentication` header, or is it `Authorization`?

Comment: look at your factory, you are returning function instead of object literal and also use `request: function(config) {....`

Comment: Really weird, same problem. The most amazing part is that I didn't touch my code and it's broken. Seeking for the change, everything is stable. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your authentication intercepter factory as like below

```
angular.module('authService', [])
    .factory('AuthInterceptor', function() {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                config.headers.Authentication = 'thisIsATestToken';
                return config;
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in the main module itself

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .run(['$http', function($http) {
      $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'thisIsATestToken';
    }])
```

Comment: I had tried that too. When I look at the request the header is not sent.